# pandas - create new column based on duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to combine records that have an identical id number. For example, suppose I have this DataFrame:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 2, 4], 'animal': ['dog', 'cat', 'bear', 'mouse']})

# just rearranging the order a bit
df=df[['id', 'animal', 'name']]

  id animal name
  1   dog   john
  2   cat   mary
  2   bear  mary
  4   mouse joe
```

What I'd like to end up with is a way to get the following:

```
id  name  animal  more_animals
 1  john   dog      NaN
 2  mary   cat      bear
 4  joe    mouse    NaN
```

I could use `df[df.duplicated('id', 'last')]` to find the duplicated rows, then loop through each duplicated id and add details to the new column but wondered if there was something a bit more elegant.

Anything come to mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
df.groupby('id')['animal'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x))).unstack()
```

Which gives you:

```
        0     1
id             
1     dog  None
2     cat  bear
4   mouse  None
```

Comment: This is great but I added a small edit. Basically, could this method be modified to work if there were more than two columns?

Comment: Ahhh yes, just add more to the groupby: `df.groupby(['id', 'name'])['animal'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x))).unstack()`

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Big help! Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Try using `cumcount` create the new key then `pivot`

```
newdf=df.assign(Newid=df.groupby('id').cumcount())
newdf.pivot('id','Newid','animal')
Out[448]: 
Newid      0     1
id                
1        dog  None
2        cat  bear
4      mouse  None
```

Comment: This is great but I added a small edit. Basically, could this method be modified to work if there were more than two columns?

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import count

d = defaultdict(count)

i, r = pd.factorize([*zip(df.id, df.name)])
j = np.array([next(d[x]) for x in i])

n, m = len(r), j.max() + 1

b = np.empty((n, m), dtype=np.object)
b[i, j] = df.animal

d1 = pd.DataFrame(r.tolist(), columns=['id', 'name'])
d2 = pd.DataFrame(b, columns=['animal', 'more_animal'])
d1.join(d2)

   id  name animal more_animal
0   1  john    dog        None
1   2  mary    cat        bear
2   4   joe  mouse        None
```

Comment: wow that's crazy! Lots there for me to learn from. Thank you.